# Center text vertically in split boxes & sibling box

Tags: html, css

How can I center text 'One'  vertically with respect to the parent box '#container' using only CSS 2.1 in the following code without using table ? Text '2.1' and text '2.2' also need to be centered vertically in the green boxes.

```
    <div id="container">
            <div id="col-1">
                One
            </div>
            <div id="col-2">
                <span>2.1</span>
                <span>2.2</span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid crimson;
            vertical-align: text-bottom;
        }
        #col-1, #col-2 {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #col-2 span {
            display: block;
            height: 48px;
            line-height: 48px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wa3r7d6j/

Comment: If you are restricted to CSS 2.1 then why not use a `table`?

Comment: Is  `table` the only way to center text 'One' ?

Comment: No...but why can't you use a table?

Comment: see the http://jsfiddle.net/wa3r7d6j/2/ ... text is vertically align middle

Comment: @anji The alignment is done by the line-height...it has nothing to do with `vertical-align` in your demo.

Comment: I just want to achieve the output in a different way and it is a constraint as well.

Comment: Constraint?...is this homework or something?

Comment: Ya  it is a kind of exercise for me & I know the solution using tables.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/wa3r7d6j/3/. you need like this?

Comment: Here's the trimmed one : http://jsfiddle.net/xh2mg81p/.

Comment: Ya I need solution like the one provided by Ketan as it does not depend on the height. However thanks anji,ketan & Paulie_D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change in css:

```
#col-1, #col-2 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

remove : `height:100%;` from `#col-1, #col-2`

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa3r7d6j/3/) here.